# Android studio - Complete operation with "app" (Open .txt file with the app)

Tags: android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, txt

the thing I want to do is to share a txt file through whatsapp and open it with my app, converting datas written in it, to be able to use them in the application.

I've read something about the "BroadcastReceiver", but what I found didn't work as well.

I attach a pic to let you understand better,

thank you for help!

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WxRY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved, in manifest, inside the activity:

```
        <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
```